# Отсутствие перевода в справке очереди "Сообщения низкого качества"

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка

[Справка про очередь сообщений низкого качества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality) имеет следующий вид:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался найти как перевести самому, но немного не понял как в тулу ввести для поиска строку. Так же я думаю стоит добавить скобку в конце

> Рекомендовать закрытие или Закрыть, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть закрыт (см. What does it mean if a question is "closed"?`

чтобы было так:

> Рекомендовать закрытие или Закрыть, если вы считаете, что вопрос должен быть закрыт (см. What does it mean if a question is "closed"?)

Comment: Тексты справок **не переводятся** через систему перевода transifex/traducir. Их закачивает на сайт сотрудник компании.